# Coverity Set Up (Cygwin Warning)?

Tags: cygwin, installation, coverity-prevent, anthill

I am currently trying to run Coverity Prevent and I believe I have everything set up appropriately on my windows 7 build machine.  I have run it with AnthillPro and when my code finishes and gets to Coverity it says that everything was built fine and the only error I get is:

```
Warning: Cygwin pathname conversion ignored; no applicable
         'bash'/'mount', 'cygpath', or registry keys found.
```

I have even tried to install Cygwin to see if this could rectify the problem and I still end up with the same error.

---

I am currently using AnthillPro 3.7 and Coverity 5.5.3.  The build log says that I have warnings but no errors and that it hasn't emitted anything.  I have tried to run a script directly from the machine (not server) itself and I have the same error as I do using the Coverity Prevent in Anthill

This is the only information I get at the bottom of the build log.

```
Run from AnthillPro:
Build time (cov-build overall): 00:00:17.753597

[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
For more details, please look at: 
  d:\Coverity\Intermediate\AllToolsProjects.sln_pc_vs2010\build-log.txt


Run from Script:
  The cov-build FAILED.

This may be because less than 90 percent of units were successfully compiled
Check for errors here:

  D:\\Coverity\Scripts\build_AllToolsProjects.sln_pc_vs2010.bat
  D:\\Coverity\Intermediate\AllToolsProjects.sln_pc_vs2010\build-log.txt
  D:\\Coverity\Configuration\pc_vs2010
```

Comment: More information is needed.  How are you wrapping your build in cov-build?  Are any files emitted - just because there was a warning about paths doesn't mean nothing worked.   What version of AnthillPro are you using?  What version of Coverity (Prevent? or Static Analysis?)  Are you trying to use AnthillPro provided integration?

Comment: You should add clarification as comments, not answer to the original question.  It sounds like maybe you didn't configure the compiler.  What compiler are you using in this build?  Did you run cov-configure for it?  Did that complete without errors?

Comment: By the way, is the native compiler doing any compiling?  cov-build only works when it can observe the native compiler (the one you configured) compiling files, so if you're not doing a clean or rebuild then there will be nothing to compile.

Comment: I tried to add my comment to your original question, but it would not accept it and I didn't want you to think that I was not appreciative or just not responding.  I am doing clean, sync and build everytime I try it.  I have no errors, just warnings and it says build failed.  It also tells me to check the compilers configurations and I have... I am using Visual Studios 2010 and the compiler is DEVENV.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't configured the compiler - that's when you tell your Coverity Analysis installation which compiler you are using.   `devenv` is not a compiler, `cl.exe` is.

Run the following command:

```
coverity-analysis-dir/bin/cov-configure --msvc
```

This will say that you are using the `cl.exe` compiler and it's of type `msvc` no matter where it's installed.

Then rerun your Coverity build and see if it captures more of your compilations.